# Best way to get text similar to the given context

Tags: java, sqlite, search

An example would be a search function on a website. Though, this is quite similar and I'm using Sqlite. So should I just use the sql clause "LIKE" or is there a better way to do this? (well, not mainly performance wise but returns better search results)

Answer (score 1):

You might search for [**fuzzy mathing algorithms**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic), notably [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) and [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

A notable Java library for this is [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you :) I shall investigate Lucene and will probably just use it and not re-invent the wheel.